# I have a python script that seems to hang and does not finish returning back to the cmd prompt

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script that opens a *text file*, takes the first line, does a few mouse events, then contiunes onwards, removing the text line and going onto the next

This runs in a loop, during 10 iterations.

The script runs to the end, but it never seems to end in the **windows command prompt** returning back, it seems to be stuck, maybe in a loop.

```
from pyautogui import moveTo, click, typewrite, hotkey
import time
import random
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread

# Open the text file and read all lines
with open('prompts.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Limit the number of lines to process
num_lines = min(len(lines), 10)

# Create a Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Script Progress")
window.geometry("200x150")  # Set the window size

# Create a label to display the countdown
countdown_label = tk.Label(window, text="Countdown: {}".format(num_lines))
countdown_label.pack()

# Function to stop the script
def stop_script():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Stop Script", "Are you sure you want to stop the script?"):
        window.destroy()

# Create a stop button
stop_button = tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=stop_script, width=10, height=3)  # Set the button size
stop_button.pack()

# Function to update the countdown label
def update_countdown_label(count):
    countdown_label.config(text="Countdown: {}".format(count))

# Function to perform the script logic
def run_script():
    # Loop until the counter reaches the specified number of lines or window is closed
    for i in range(num_lines):
        # Check if window is closed
        if not window.winfo_exists():
            break

        # Left click inside the text field
        click(405, 995, 1, 1, 'left')

        # Generate random sleep duration between 1 and 10 seconds
        sleep_duration = random.uniform(3, 8)

        # Wait for the message to be sent
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)

        # Type / to get prompt
        typewrite('/', interval=0.2)

        # Generate random sleep duration between 1 and 10 seconds
        sleep_duration = random.uniform(5, 10)

        # Wait for the message to be sent
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)

        # Press enter
        typewrite(['enter'])

        # Generate random sleep duration between 1 and 10 seconds
        sleep_duration = random.uniform(5, 20)

        # Wait for the message to be sent
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)

        # Extract the first line and remove it from the list
        first_line = lines.pop(0).strip()

        # Remove the first line from the file
        with fileinput.input('prompts.txt', inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file:
                if line.strip() != first_line:
                    print(line, end='')

        # Copy the first line to the clipboard
        pyperclip.copy(first_line)

        # Paste text from clipboard
        hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

        # Generate random sleep duration between 1 and 10 seconds
        sleep_duration = random.uniform(5, 20)

        # Wait for the message to be sent
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)

        # Press enter
        typewrite(['enter'])

        # Update the countdown label
        update_countdown_label(num_lines - i - 1)

    # Close the window when the script is finished
    window.destroy()

# Run the script logic in a separate thread
script_thread = Thread(target=run_script)
script_thread.start()

# Set window attributes for focus and stay on top
window.lift()
window.attributes('-topmost', True)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Any help in finding why the script does not finish or end the loop, if its stuck in one, would be helpful, thanks in advance

I have tired running the script in a **windows cmd prompt**, but it does not seem to end to return back to the **windows command prompt**.

Comment: Do you mean "cmd" by "cmb"?

Comment: yes sorry is the windows cmd app, which i have used to run the script, when run in it, it never returns back to the prompt, leading me to beleieve the script is hanging maybe in a loop or something

Comment: You could have written "cmd" instead of "cmb" then. You can still [edit] your question to fix this and other spelling mistakes.

Comment: fixed the spelling error on the title thanks for the heads up

Comment: Why did you not fix the remaining spelling errors as well?

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproductible example ?